# Array structure for Shopping Basket

Tags: php, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to implement multidimensional array that hold data of Pizza id's with options and extras id's.

Let look at the following scenario...

Customer wants

- Two 'Chicken Pizza' (`ProductID:12`) - '10 inches' (`OptionsID:4`) with extras of Ham and Tuna (`ExtrasID: 5,10`)
- One 'Chicken Pizza' (`ProductID:12`) - '10 inches' (`OptionsID:4`) with extras of Sweet Corn (`ExtrasID: 2`)
- One 'Chicken Pizza' (`ProductID:12`) - '14 inches' (`OptionsID:2`) with no extras
- Eleven 'Vegetarian Pizza' (`ProductID:35`) - '7 inches' (`OptionsID:52`) with no extras

See the following code below that match the scenario... Im I doing it right? or what can be done to improve it and readable?

```
//Two 'Chicken Pizza' (ProductID:12) - '10 inches' (OptionsID:4) 
//With extras of Ham and Tuna (ExtrasID: 5,10)
$option4[] = array(
    'quantity' => 2,
    'extras_id' => array(5, 10)
);

//One 'Chicken Pizza' (ProductID:12) - '10 inches' (OptionsID:4) 
//With extras of Sweet Corn (ExtrasID: 2)
$option4[] = array(
    'quantity' => 1,
    'extras_id' => array(2)
);

//One 'Chicken Pizza' (ProductID:12) - '14 inches' (OptionsID:2) 
//With no extras
$option2[] = array(
    'quantity' => 1,
    'extras_id' => array()
);

//Eleven 'Vegetarian Pizza' (ProductID:35) - '7 inches' (OptionsID:52) 
//With no extras
$option52[] = array(
    'quantity' => 11,
    'extras_id' => array()
);

//Hold data of Customer Orders 
$shoppingBasket = array(
    "ShopID_24" => array(
        'ProductID' => array(
            '12' => array(
                'OptionID' => array(
                    '4' => $option4,
                    '2' => $option2
                )
            ),
            '35' => array(
                'OptionID' => array(
                    '52' => $option52
                )
            ),
        )
    )
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($shoppingBasket);
echo "</pre>";
```

**print_r output:**

```
Array
(
    [ShopID_24] => Array
        (
            [ProductID] => Array
                (
                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [OptionID] => Array
                                (
                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [quantity] => 2
                                                    [extras_id] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 5
                                                            [1] => 10
                                                        )
                                                )
                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [quantity] => 1
                                                    [extras_id] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 2
                                                        )
                                                )

                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [quantity] => 1
                                                    [extras_id] => Array ()
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [35] => Array
                        (
                            [OptionID] => Array
                                (
                                    [52] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [quantity] => 11
                                                    [extras_id] => Array ()
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider doing this by modeling the same data in a few custom PHP objects.  In this case you might have a shop object with products, and product objects with options.  This is really quick off the top of my head:

```
class Shop {

    private $_products = array();

    public function getProducts() 
        { return $this->_products;}

    public function addProduct(Product $product) 
        { $this->_products[] = $product; 
          return $this;
        }

}

class Product {
    private $_options = array();

    public function getOptions()
        { return $this->_options; }

    public function addOption(Option $option)
        { $this->_options[] = $option;
          return $this;
        }
}

class Option {
    private $_optionKey;
    private $_optionValue;

    public function getKey()
        { return $this->_optionKey; }

    public function getKey()
        { return $this->_optionValue; }

    public function setOption($key, $value)
        { 
          $this->_optionKey = $key;
          $this->_optionValue = $value;
          return $this;
        }
}
```

What does this get you?  For starters, you can define limits and parameters to what you can store in this, while with the nested array that you are using, there is absolutely no enforcement of structure or value.  You can also define other methods that allow you to actually DO things with these bits of data.

If you absolutely MUST have an array version of these, you can implement something like a `toArray()` method in each of these that will convert the objects into an array to be consumed by some other bit of code.  You might also consider reading up on a few interfaces such as iterator and countable in the PHP manual.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great example. I will look more into this and test it.. I thought I have to use array version because I can store into '$_SESSION'. For example when customer click on the Add button to add basket then its store into session. I guess its safe to store object to session?  Could you provide little test at the bottom your code? So I get the idea what to do. thanks.

Comment: I am trying to test your example, cant get it work: `$shop = new Shop(); $shop->addProduct("Item 1");`

Comment: Note the method signature: addProduct(Product $product).  This means it is expecting an object of type product.  What you need is $shop->addProduct(new Product("Item 1"));

Comment: Also, objects can be serialized and stored in the session.  See the Serializable Interface http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php

Answer (score 1):

You set up one array on the beginning, fine. Now use it in the right way.

```
$option['ShopID_'.$id]; //where $id is obviusly the id number;
```

Now fill the $option array with the orders.

```
$option['ShopID_'.$id]['ProductId_'.$pid][] = array(
    'quantity' => 1,
    'extras_id' => array(2), //maybe a string is enough here (?) (e.g. '2,5,etc..')
    'inches' => $inches
);
```

`$pid` is obviusly the pizza Id you are searching for..

as well this is just a "static" example!

Comment: Thanks, I understood your example but if you scenario again - I mention that customer can have two same product id and option id but different extras.

Comment: $option['ShopID_'.$id]['ProductId_'.$pid][] last 2 brackets are for adding more "optionsId".. that array identifies one kind of pizza with same extras. But OO examples above are for sure better than this ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use OO programming, this saves you a lot of headache!
Try something like this:

```
<?php
class Extra
{
    var $id;
    var $name;
    var $amount;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = 0;
        $this->name = '';
        $this->amount = 0;
    }
}
class Option
{
    var $id;
    var $name;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = 0;
        $this->name = '';
    }
}
class Pizza
{
    var $id;
    var $name;
    var $options;
    var $extras;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = 0;
        $this->name = '';
        $this->options = array();
        $this->extras = array();
    }
}
?>
```

And to test it:

```
<?php
$pizzas = array();
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    $pizza = new Pizza();
    $pizza->id = $i;
    $pizza->name = 'Pizza '.$i;
    for($j=0; $j<$i; $j++)
    {
        $option = new Option();
        $option->id = $j;
        $option->name = 'Option '.$j;
        $pizza->options[] = $option;
    }
    for($k=$i; $k>0; $k--)
    {
        $extra = new Extra();
        $extra->id = $k;
        $extra->name = 'Extra '.$k;
        $extra->amount = $k;
        $pizza->extras[] = $extra;
    }
    $pizzas[] = $pizza;
}
print_r($pizzas);
?>
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look now and test it :) That is a great ideas.. I've implemented basket multidimensional array as example to store into `$SESSION` array - For Example, on the frontend customer click on the Add Button add basket. I guess its normal to store Class Object into session?

Comment: Yes, you can use serialize() and unserialize() to save/load objects from $_SESSION.

Comment: I've just tested your code and it look great. Just one issue, the Extra Object need to be in Option Object.  Each Option come with extras. You can have two same options id but different extras. Have a quick look at the scenario again, thanks :)